# Cannot convert 'idt_entry_t (*)[256] to u8int*

Tags: c++, c, kernel, osdev

I am trying to do

```
memset(&idt_entries, 0, sizeof(idt_entry_t)*256);
```

which produces

> error: cannot convert 'idt_entry_t (*)[256] {aka idt_entry_struct (*)[256]}' to 'u8int* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '1' to 'void memset(u8int*, u8int, u32int)'

If it helps, it is C code wraped in `extern "C" {...}`.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the declaration of `idt_entries`.  I'm confused by the `(*)` in the error message.

Comment: It might help if you used the right types for `memset`'s arguments rather than hard-coding bogus types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idt_entries` is an array 256 of `idt_entry_t`.

The value of the array `idt_entries` is a pointer to its first element. Use this value as the first argument to `memset`. The size of your array is `sizeof idt_entries`.

So here is how to correctly call `memset` to set all array elements to  0:

```
memset(idt_entries, 0, sizeof idt_entries);
```

Comment: it seems you are using a non standard `memset` function. You'll have to cast the first arguments to the type of your first parameter of `memset` function. Cast the first argument in my example to `uint8t *`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling this as C++?

Add a cast.

`memset ((u8int*)idt_entries, 0, sizeof(idt_entry_t)*256);`

Answer (score 0):

`idt_entries` is already a pointer.  Remove the ampersand:

```
memset (idt_entries, 0, sizeof(idt_entry_t)*256);
```